# Understanding Python map function + range

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

I'm trying to understand the difference between these lines of code:

```
list(''.join(map(lambda x: str(x * 3), range(1, 4))))
```

Out: `['3', '6', '9']` as expected.

However:

```
list(''.join(map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4))))
```

outputs `['5', '1', '0', '1', '5']`, while I expected: `['5','10','15']`

In the same way that

```
[x for x in map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4))]
```

ouputs `['5','10','15']`.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 18):

You first *joined* all strings together into one big string, and then converted that string to a list, which always results in all the individual characters being pulled out as elements:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4)))
['5', '10', '15']
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4)))
'51015'
>>> list(''.join(map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4))))
['5', '1', '0', '1', '5']
```

As you can see above, all you need to do is remove the `str.join()` call, just use `list()` directly on `map()`:

```
list(map(lambda x: str(x * 5), range(1, 4)))
```

Answer (score 2):

All numbers in the first snippet are single digit numbers, so joining them and splitting them won't make a difference. See [Martijn Pieters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769452/2607571). In the second it will make a difference because some are two digit numbers.

Example:

```
[3, 6, 9] join -> 369 split -> ["3", "6", "9"]
[5, 10, 15] join -> 51015 split -> ["5", "1", "0", "1", "5"]
```

Comment: Note: Poster removed comment on Martijn Pieters answer to check the edit